# "RESULT_CODE_MISSING_DATA" at Chromium build launch at Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, chromium

I built my own version of Chromium using [official instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md) with very slight changes in the code that do not touch the core things. When I try to launch it on Windows 10 (tried Home and LTSC), is shows "RESULT_CODE_MISSING_DATA" error on each page, including internal ones, like "settings".

The build works on Windows 10 correctly if I launch it with "compatibility to Windows 8" option, but that's a bad option as it launches with additional borders, maybe it's because of Metro UI:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUAHT.png)

The build launches on Windows 7 well without any additional changes.

I tried to build 82.x.x.x and 81.x.x.x builds, they all emerge this error on Windows 10.

I tried to do builds on multiple OS (Win7, Win10), the error still presents.

my args.gn:

```
is_debug = false
is_component_build = false
enable_nacl = false
symbol_level = 1
target_cpu = "x86" # I tried x64, same problem
blink_symbol_level = 1
proprietary_codecs = true
ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"
is_component_ffmpeg=true
is_official_build=true
```

Comment: Try building the stable versions instead. Checkout a stable version tag and build one. You are building alpha and beta versions.

Comment: I've just tried to build 79.0.3945.130, that was released as stable version, about a month ago. And see the same problem: all pages (including internal like Extensions) are not loading. It seems like I'm doing something wrong while compiling :(

Comment: Enable logging in Chromium and checkout the log file or debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several build tries I built chromium well-working after removing the `is_component_ffmpeg=true` flag from args.gn.

Thanks Asesh for helping.